# spark DF multiple Iterations on Rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, immutability

From the below data- `col5` is holding the no of fruits to be distributed among plates from `col1` to `col4`(4plates). Each time find the min from the plates(`col1` to `col4`) add 1 fruit and reduce the fruit from `col5` and repeat this process till `col5`(fruits becomes zero). Below is some sample code to find the min and add 1 fruit there. but how to do this recursively in spark - Scala.

Expected output:

[image: Expected output:]

```
  plate1 plate2 plate3  plate4  fruits  
  1 2   3   4   3   
  6 7   8   1   2   
  2 4   6   8   5
```

Iteration 1:

```
  2 2   3   4   2   
  6 7   8   2   1   
  3 4   6   8   4
```

Iteration 2:

```
  3 2   3   4   1   (If 2 plates has the same min value , left precedence)
  6 7   8   3   0   
  4 4   6   8   3
```

Iteration 3:

```
  3 3   3   4   0   
  6 7   8   3   0   
  5 4   6   8   2
```

Iteration 4:

```
  3 3   3   4   0   
  6 7   8   3   0   
  5 5   6   8   1
```

Iteration 5:

```
  3 3   3   4   0   
  6 7   8   3   0   
  6 5   6   8   0
```

code for first iteration:

```scala
      val data = Seq(
        (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0),
        (6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 1.0, 2.0),
        (2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 5.0)
      )
      val columns = List("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
      val df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(columns: _*)

      val updatedColumns = columns.map { colName =>
        functions.when(col(colName) === functions.least(columns.map(col): _*), col(colName) + 1).otherwise(col(colName)).alias(colName)
      }

      val updatedDF = df.select(updatedColumns: _*)
      updatedDF.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each row is independent, then I think it is easier to iterate within the mapping function of each row until you get the final result, so that you don't have to iterate over the whole df multiple times.

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val data = Seq(
        (1, 2, 3, 4, 3),
        (6, 7, 8, 1, 2),
        (2, 4, 6, 8, 5)
      )

val columns = List("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
val arrayDf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).map(row =>  {
    var plates: List[Int] = row.productIterator.toList.map {case i: Int => i}
    var store: Int = plates.last // Assuming last column is the store 
    plates = plates.dropRight(1) // remove the store column
    (0 until store).toList.foreach(i => {
        val min = plates.min
        val index = plates.indexOf(min)
        store -=1
        plates = plates.updated(index, min + 1)
    })
    plates :+ store // Add the store at the end (which is always 0) 
}).toDF(Seq("result"): _*)

// Convert the list of result into columns again
val df = arrayDf.select(columns.zipWithIndex.map{case (name, idx) => arrayDf("result")(idx).alias(name)}: _*)

df.show()
```

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   3|   3|   3|   4|   0|
|   6|   7|   8|   3|   0|
|   6|   5|   6|   8|   0|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks @Isalm Elbanna. This is working but I need to perform this on 200 columns and around 50 million records.

Comment: Hi @user22006369, I have updated the answer to make it more generic for a big list of columns

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate dataFrames. It Is possible to use dedicated higher order function and sql methods.

It Is possible to use collect in order to get an Array[Row] and then apply a scala method that takes that Array and processes it in order to return the desired output.

You should write something like this

```
def process(input: Array[Row]): DataFrame =
 {
   // iterate the input here 
   // do not hesitate to write some code and share your work with us. It is always better to make effort and try something before asking for a solution
   result
 } 

val resultDF = process(updatedDF.collect())
```

Of course there is multiple ways to perform the processing, I suggested using collect but it may be a bad choice because you'll save the results in memory so it depends on your dataframe size and cluster/laptop configurations.

You can also use spark sql methods, udf ect...